# Weird behaviour with Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a burger menu that needs to register a click (I will then expand the menu..)

The HTML of the burger icon/menu is:

```
<div class="burger-menu-holder">
    <a href="#" id="burger-menu">
        &#9776;
    </a>
</div>
```

The CSS is a simple:

```css
#burger-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

The Javascript to register the click and run the function is:

```
var burger = document.getElementById("burger-menu");
burger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(burger.style.display=='block'){
        alert("LOL");
    }
}, false);
```

However when I click on the menu nothing happens. There's no errors in the console, however when I remove `if(burger.style.display == 'block')` it works, leading me believe that for some reason it's not testing the CSS properties correctly.

Comment: Just fyi: `burger.addEventListener` will fail on IE8 or less, because those are using `attachEvent` instead. If you need to support them, then laziest would be using `burger.onclick = function(){...}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that burger doesn't have `style="display: block;"` initially (even though it's visible), so `burger.style.display == 'block'` fails.

Testing element CSS styles is not very reliable approach. I would go with classes:

```
var burger = document.getElementById("burger-menu");
burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (burger.className === 'show') {
        alert("LOL");
    }
}, false);
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="burger-menu" class="show">&#9776;</a>
```

And in CSS:

```
.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Additional advantage of the class name is that you can easily change and style `show` behavior without affecting javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

try it like this:

```
<div class="burger-menu-holder">
    <a href="#" id="burger-menu" style="display: block;">
        &#9776;
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM property `element.style.something` will get only inline defined styles, such as:

```
<a href="#" id="burger-menu" style="display: block;">
```

For testing styles, use css classes. (Look at **dfsq**'s answer)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a manually-set "style" parameter and the computed style.

So look at eg getComputedStyle in webkit/opera, currentStyle in IE. The various toolkits offer nicer ways to access this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it's not an optimal way of testing. However, if you want to, you could use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle), then [`getPropertyValue`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljswreks.php) to get the `display` value, like so:

```
var burger = document.getElementById("burger-menu");

burger.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Get the computed display value after the stylesheet has been applied
  var display = window.getComputedStyle(burger).getPropertyValue("display");
  if(display === "block"){
     alert("LOL");
  }
}, false);
```

---

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/F5Gsr/)